# jquerymobile css for standard - laptop/desktop - web browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

In my rails app I currently have a *.mobile.erb and *.html.erb file for each view.

jquerymobile has a great set of css div tags. I'd love to create the same set of tags I use most frequently (eg: data-role="page|header|navbar|content") but have this dictate a clean lookking laptop/desktop browser theme as opposed to a mobile theme.

With this, in my rails app I'd still render either the jquerymobile css and js files or the standard jquery/browser css and js files but I think I could probably get away with re-using the views by referencing the same div tags that render differently based on the platform. I'd love to use something that exists as opposed to creating my own. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: so you are looking for a jquery mobile desktop css?

Comment: yep - I'd like to use the same div tags but have it render a clean desktop page as opposed to a mobile optimized page.

Comment: ok. as far as I know there is no Desktop-CSS available (yet). I started to work on one for a client, so it is not generic. Question is, why don't you use the CSS JQM provides? I'm using it for mobile/tablet/desktop applications and think it works just fine. You can simply use a CSS grid ([1140](http://cssgrid.net/),[960](http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/)), so you can structure your content. Only problem is multi-column layouts if you don't want to use the CSS-based approach used in JQM docs. If you have that, shrink the font-size and you are good to go.